# How to hide WhatsApp messages notifications

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, whatsapp-messenger, notification-bar

How can I hide WhatsApp messages in notification panel? I don't want to see incoming message preview on my notification panel.

What utility can let me do this?

Answer (score 1):

Go to settings > Apps > Whatsapp
And Uncheck 'show notifications'.

Answer (score 0):

Hiding Whatsapp messages of targeted contacts is not possible, but if you want to you can hide all incoming message on Whatsapp and activate them again if you have some private time for yourself. Just download Mobiwol and block Whatsapp on it. Messages for you will not be delivered, but you can open Whatsapp. If you have the phone to yourself just unblock Whatsapp and you will receive all messages sent to you in the meantime. I hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following image helps you ... once u get to the settings, click notification then u should see this:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you go to *Settings › Sounds & Notifications › Application Notifications,* you can define which apps are permitted to send notifications to your notification area. Look for the *WhatsApp* entry there, and turn it off – and you should be rid of WA notifications, while all others continue to work as intended.